# Ionic 2 range touchend event

Tags: angular, range, ionic2

I´m trying to get the value of a range slider with Ionic 2 at the end of an input.

In the [doumentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/#output-events) the only availible event is the ionChange, which triggers several times during an input, and I only need the last value to perform an action.

I tried to add the touchend event manually but the event is ignored.

Here´s also a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLQXHX4eyZ7bBiKGBUsx?p=preview) with the Problem.

```
<ion-range (ionChange)="showVal($event)" (touchend)="presentValue(event)" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="currentTime" color="danger">
          <ion-icon small range-left name="sunny"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
     </ion-range>
```

Does anybody know a way to listen to an touchend event on the range slider in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 8):

There is also the `ionBlur` and `ionFocus` event on the range input you could use.

The `ionFocus` fires when you are sliding through the range
and the `ionBlur` is fired when you have released the range item

```
<ion-range (ionBlur)="rangeBlurred($event)" (ionFocus)="rangeFocused($event)">
```

Answer (score 3):

"debounce" attribute of ion-range would work.
"debounce" adds delay to emit the ionChange function from component.

```
<ion-range debounce="700" (ionChange)="someFunction($event)"></ion-range>
```

(700 is delay time in milliseconds) 700 works fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use debounce time in Ion-range to capture the event at the END of a drag only, not at each step through the drag of the range input slide.

`<ion-range min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="percent" debounce="500" (ionChange)="onSliderChanged()"> </ion-range>`

Answer (score 0):

**`(ionKnobMoveEnd)`** Emitted when the user finishes moving the range knob, whether through mouse drag, touch gesture