# How to detect touchstart and touchend on knob of ion-range

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I use Ionic 2 for develop my app. I want to know method to detect touchstart and touchend on knob of ion-range. I will use that method for show some element when knob is pressing and remove element when knob doesn't press. (It's like iBooks or Google Play Book when you press knob and show title each page) How can I detect it ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use (ionBlur)="rangeBlurred($event)" as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444852/1142571

Answer (score 2):

You can use `touchstart` and `touchend` events.

```
<div (touchstart)="touchstart($event)" (touchend)="touchend($event)">
```

Found the idea here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/button-hold-event/48034/2